# Why is the output different from what I expected?

Tags: c++, codelite

I run this code but the output was different from what I expected. 
The output:

```
c = 1324
v = 1324.99
```

I expected that the output should be 1324.987 for `v`. Why is the data in `v` different from output?

I'm using code lite on Windows 8 32.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double v = 1324.987;
    int n;
    n = int (v);
    cout << "c = " << n << endl;
    cout << "v = " << v << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: I expected that the output should be 1324.987 for v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default precision when printing with `cout` is 6, so only 6 decimal places will be displayed. The number is rounded to the nearest value, that's why you saw 1324.99. You need to [set a higher precision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to see the more "correct" value

However, setting the precision too high may print out a lot of garbage digits behind, because binary floating-point types cannot store all decimal floating-point values exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Floating point types inherit rounding errors as a result of their fixed width representations. For more information, see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#680).

Comment: while useful information, that's not what is going on here; in fact the default precision for display is 6. The output would be 1324.99 even if there were no rounding errors. `double` has more than enough precision to store 1324.987.